# Is there any game for understanding elevator physics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, resource-recommendations, simulations, education, software

I'm a physics teacher and I'm wondering if there's any game for physics elevator problems (weight in accelerating elevator) that the student can play with to better understand in what situations the weight is less or more